# how to edit the ~/.bashrc file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default editor for rosed is vim. To set the default editor to something else edit your ~/.bashrc file to include:
export EDITOR='emacs -nw'
But I don't know how to edit the  ~/.bashrc file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/87866/how-to-edit-the-%7E/.bashrc-file/) by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To edit it:

> vi ~/.bashrc

and add that line. You could also use (as SaiHV answered)

> gedit ~/.bashrc".

Make sure to

> source ~/.bashrc

after editing it.

---

Originally posted by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) with karma: 211 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) on 2013-10-06**:
but how to add that line when I input: vi ~/.bashrc? I am new at this, could you give me the details, thanks so much.

**Comment by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) on 2013-10-06**:
Thanks. I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use "gedit ~/.bashrc".

---

Originally posted by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) with karma: 275 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-06**:
After you edit it you need to open a new terminal for it to take effect.